# Show that ${\rm rank}(P)=k$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a homework problem, and I don't know how to proceed. I am given that $\{q_1,\dots,q_k\}$ are an orthonormal basis for a subspace $W$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here's what I do know or have already proved over the course of this problem:

1. The matrix of the orthogonal projection onto $W$, $P$, is $P=q_1q_1^T+\ldots+q_kq_k^T$. $P$ is symmetric and $P^2=P$.
2. If $Q$ is the $n\times k$ matrix whose columns are the orthonormal basis vectors of $W$, so $Q=[q_1\cdots q_k]$, then $P=QQ^T$.

I am trying to prove that $\operatorname{rank}(P)=k$. I have been thinking about this for a while, since $Q$ and $Q^T$ are not square matrices, so I can't define them as orthogonal or use the Fundamental Theorem of Invertible Matrices. How would you go about solving this?

Comment: Just a hint as it's your homework: don't bother with matrices.  The rank of $P$ is the dimension of its image - can you work out what is the image of the orthogonal projection onto $W$?

Comment: That would just be $Px=QQ^Tx$, where $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, right?

Comment: It's simpler than that @Math. The orthogonal projection onto $W$ projects vectors onto the subspace $W$, so $\operatorname{Range} P \subseteq W$. Since $Pw = w$ for all $w \in W$, we have $W \subseteq \operatorname{Range} P$. That is, the range is $W$.

Comment: Additionally, you could just show that $\text{rank} QQ^T=\text{rank} Q^T$ for any real matrix $Q$.

Comment: Thank you all so much, I solved it!